# Can't understand why `trait Hello[+A] { def test[B<:A] }` can't be compiled

Tags: scala, generics, contravariance, type-systems

I can understand why the following code can't be compiled:

```
trait Hello[+A] {
    def test[B<:A](x: B)
}
```

Because:

```
val child: Hello[String] = new Hello[String] {
    def test[B <: String](x: B) = x.substring(1)
}
val parent: Hello[Any] = child
parent.test(123) // child.test can't handle integer
```

But I can't understand well why the following code can't be compiled:

```
trait Hello[+A] {
    def test[B<:A]
}
```

The difference is the later one doesn't have parameters, we can't pass any value to the `test` method.

Why compiler still think it's invalid?

Answer (score 4):

When you trying doing it in repl, it says:

```
scala> trait Hello[+A] {
     |     def test[B<:A](x: B)
     | }
<console>:8: error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type  <: A of type B
           def test[B<:A](x: B)
                    ^
```

Rightly so. Imagine if this was possible and you could:

```
val x:Hello[Dog] = new Hello[Dog]{..}
val y:Hello[Animal] = x
y.test(Cat)//Oops
```

About the parameters, what makes you think it makes it safe without any arguments. You could get the variable using say `implicitly` and do dangerous stuff which compiler will not stop you. Example:

```
def test[B<:A]:B = this
```

Comment: The example `def test[B<:A]:B = this` is not good. Actually, B is invariant, it may appear in the return-type position. See compilable example: `trait Cat[-A] { def meow[B <: A](x: B): B }`

Comment: I think the reason is that `B` may be inferred from parameter, but also may be specified. So `val parent: Hello[Any] = child; parent.test[Any]`, we can specify `Any` to `test`, but which is not the subtype of `String`.